# Reformatting dates from a csv and writing them into a new csv

Tags: python, csv

I just started to learn python so that I could make a program that could manipulate bank statement cvs files, but I do not know very much. I have one csv file with a column of dates in the format: month+day+year. Examples include 3/3/20, 12/2/20, 9/13/20, etc.

I would like to take these dates from the column and reformat them into the format: year+month+day. Examples of the format that I need them to be in include 200303, 201202, 200913, etc.

But I do not know how to get information from my original csv file and proceed to reorder it and write it into my new csv file. I am going to need a lot of explaining of the steps because I am so new to this. All help is appreciated though :)

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
        bank_statement = '/Users/annamobley/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Python/3 March 2020.csv'
# import initial bank statement
import csv

with open(bank_statement, 'rt')as initial_file:
    data = csv.reader(initial_file)
    for row in data:
        original_dates = str(row[1])

# find number of rows in the initial bank statement
file = open(bank_statement)
reader = csv.reader(file)
lines = len(list(reader))
num_lines = int(lines) - int(1)

# variables in new csv
upload_statement = 'manip_bank_statement.csv'
bank_abbreviation = "GCB"
acc_num = input('Enter the account number : ')
acc_name = input("Enter the Account Name/Description (): ")
# date format manipulation
first_2_num_year = input(
    "Input the first two numbers in the year that it is currently. Ex: If it is the year 2019, input '20': ")
import datetime as dt

post_date_original = row[1]
manipulated_date = (dt.datetime.date(dt.datetime.strptime(original_dates, '%m/%d/%y')).strftime('%y%m%d'))
final_date = str(first_2_num_year + manipulated_date)
# writing the new csv
import csv

with open(upload_statement, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for somevariable in range(num_lines):
        writer.writerow([bank_abbreviation, acc_num, acc_name, final_date])
```

I get the error message:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/annamobley/PycharmProjects/CSV_Manipulation_Project/Project.2.redo.py", line 41, in <module>
    manipulated_date = (dt.datetime.date(dt.datetime.strptime(original_dates, '%m/%d/%y')).strptime('%y%m%d'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 19
```

Comment: For example, did you try using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and use the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to parse the dates? Someone (I'd almost put money on it) is about to suggest `pandas.read_csv` and it's not helpful in understanding anything

Comment: It is the incorrect platform to ask for a tutorial; it just doesn't fit in the style of a Q&A. That said, I'm not trying to make you feel bad for having difficulties as a beginner - I started out self-taught using mostly Stack Overflow. The key point I was trying to make is that you should _just have a go_ :) The computer won't explode if you get the code wrong, but unless you start writing things and seeing how they are broken, you're not going to progress. I gave hyperlinks to those modules, did you follow them and read the examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the date using the `datetime` module.

```
import datetime as dt

day = '3/3/20'

print(
    dt.datetime.date(
        dt.datetime.strptime(day, '%m/%d/%y')
    ).strftime('%y%m%d')
)

Output:
200303
```

Here is a good resource for the `datetime` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I appreciate your answer and the resource that you provided for further reference. I am going to try this out later today and see how it goes.

Comment: How would I go about modifying this so that it would work when the input could be a date with either one or two digits in the month and the day spots? The code that you provided works in my program when the input date is for example: '3/3/20' (where in the month and day spots there is a single digit), but it does not work for dates like '12/2/20' or '12/12/20'. I tried to add multiple '%' signs and it did not work (It was just a guess don't know what I am doing). Thanks!

Comment: I modified the code above because I incorrectly read your original question.  It will work now.